# How to view request value in Apache http server submitted by user

Tags: apache-2.2

I am seeing an intermittent issues where the user request is not getting thru to the backend server which is weblogic directed from apache webserver. I would llike to see the request value in apache before redirection to weblogic. How do I see the user request values in apache?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to log the entire http request from a client as it is received by Apache.  There are a number of approaches to this issue:

- You can use a tool like `tcpdump` to take a packet trace, and then use `strings` to extract the text content of the packets.  That would look something like this:

  - Grab the packets:

    ```
    # tcpdump -w packets -s 1500 port 80 and host <client ip address>
    ```
  - Display the results:

    ```
    # strings packets
    ```

  This isn't a perfect method (the output of `strings` will contain some garbage), but it's usually a good start.
- According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20log%20request), recent versions of Apache have [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html), which "allows for the logging of all input received by Apache and/or all output sent by Apache to be logged (dumped) to the error.log file."
- I believe that [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) can also log full requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- a sniffer: `ngrep 'GET|POST' port 80`
- a tracer: `strace <apache_worker>`, `ltrace <apache_worker>`
- configure apache logs to log the content. Try to log only GETs.